# Javascript in VS2019

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, reference, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I'm working on a huge project consisting of C# and Javascript files and I'm using VS2019 with ReSharper.

Everything works well except that Intellisense can't find global variables, objects or functions defined in other files.

When I load this project in VSCode, it works super fine, finds everything, shows variables and functions inside globally defined objects and even displays a tooltip for parameters.

Is there any workaround like adding a config file to the project or changing a setting in VS or ReSharper to make it find the definition, references, and make ctrl+click to work?

P.S. switching to Typescript is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: Is your project  a asp net net framework project?

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help. Although ctrl+click works and it jumps to the definition in another file, the tooltip is still saying "any" instead of showing the whole definition including the parameters.

Comment: Could you please share a pic with us to describe the issue? In my side, it could [work well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7brbH.png) and I could see the definition of the variable. Did you use any `const`,instead, use `var`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the functions,variables,... from another js files, you could first add these reference node on top of the main js file:

```
///<reference path="xxxx\xxx.js"(the full path of the referenced js file) />
```

**Then**, you can get the functions, variables from that file.

**Besides**, there is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909704/js-css-intellisense-between-projects-in-vs-2019/59931349#59931349).